# Analysis of dictionary

Tags: algorithm, big-o, analysis, time-complexity

My first question in the analysis it is mentioned as

n+(n/2)+(n/4)+--- is atmost 2n. how we got result as atmost 2n?

> We have a collection of arrays, where array "i" has size (2 to power
>   i). Each array is either empty of full, and each is sorted. However,
>   there will be no relationship between the items in different arrays.
>   The issue of which arrays  are full and which is empty is based on the
>   binary representation of the number of items we are storing.
>
> To perform a lookup, we just do binary search in eac occupied aray. In
>   the worst case this takes time O(log(n) + log(n/2) + log(n/4) +....+1)
>   = O(log square n).
>
> Following is question on above text snippet.

1. How does author came with O(log(n) + log(n/2) + log(n/4) +....+1) ?
2. and above sum is O(log square n).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8 ... = n * (1/1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ...)

The sum 1/1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ... is a [geometric series that converges to 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series), so the result is 2n.

Apparently, the author is talking about a collection of arrays with the sizes n, n/2, n/4, ..., and he is doing a binary search in each of them. A binary search in an array with *n* elements takes *O(log n)* time, so the total time required is *O(log n + log n/2 + log n/4 + ...)*.

Comment: but in above explanation how we got array of sizes n, n/3, n/4?

Comment: @venkysmarty: "array _i_ has size _2^i_" - this gives arrays of size 1, 2, 4, 8, ..., n/8, n/4, n/2, n (assuming that _n_ is a power of 2).